# Не работает .lstrip

Tags: python

В файле пример .xml, с отступами. Хочу получить строки без отступов, однако данная конструкция почему-то не работает.

```
with open('example.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    test = file.readlines()
    _test = []
    for i in test:
        if i.startswith(' '):
            i.lstrip()
        _test.append(i)
```

Comment: Строка `i.lstrip()` ничего не делает, потому что вы никуда не сохраняете результат вызова этого метода

Comment: нет, принт `_test` после цикла выдаёт тот же результат что и принт `test`

Comment: Это никак не противоречит тому факту, что строка `i.lstrip()` ничего не делает, потому что вы никуда не сохраняете результат вызова этого метода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
with open('test_ui.ui', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    test = file.readlines()
    _test = []
    for i in test:
        _test.append(i.lstrip())
        
print(* _test)
```